# Python module "preprocess" - does that exist?

Tags: python, module

In my python code I want to use a module called "topicmodels" (that can be found here https://github.com/sekhansen/text-mining-tutorial). The problem with this module is that whenever I want to "import topicmodels" in my Python code, I get  the error message: 
ImportError: No module name preprocess, more specifically in that topicmodels module is a Python file *init*.py that contains the line " from preprocess import * ". I googled and did not find a python module called preprocess - can anybody help me out on this? 
(I am using Kubuntu and Python 3.5.2 | Anaconda 4.2.0).

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is written for Python 2. You're on Python 3. The failing import is an [implicit relative import](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/), which Python 3 prohibits.

Run it on Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install preprocess
```

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/preprocess/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
pip install preprocessing
```

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/preprocessing/